# How do I make a copy of an Array, which I can return in a public method?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I got told that I shouldn't have public methods returning Arrays for "future" security purposes. Instead they should be private, and if I wanna return an Array it would have to be some kind of copy in another method.

This is how it looks now..

```
public Object[] ownedObject() {

    return objectArr;
}
```

If I make this private the class that needs it doesn't recognize the method above.

Thing is I need to use the contents in that Array in said, other class, and the total project, as I have it right now with 5 different classes, works (with the returning Array-methods set to Public and not private).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Copy array of non-primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366303/java-copy-array-of-non-primitive-type)

Answer (score 2):

As you are concerned with security aspect of this problem you might want to [distinguish between shallow copy and deep copy of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1175620/1602555). If your array contains mutable objects you probably need a deep copy of every single element in the array to ensure that state is not leaking from your object.

Assuming that you array is of type `MyType` with [a copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29362169/1602555):

```
public MyType[] ownedObject() {
    MyType[] copyArr = new MyType[objectArr.lenght];
    for (int i = 0; i < objectArr.lenght; i++) {
        copyArr[i] = new MyType(objectArr[i]);
    }
    return copyArr;
}
```

There are also other ways [to deep copy an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64066/1602555).

Comment: Ah I see! It is indeed a copy constructor. 

But it has the parameters [String, String, int, int] so it won't take [i] as parameter when making the copyArr. Which gives me some kind of problems.

Comment: Alternatively, would there be any reasonable arguments for the original method to STAY public, and if so what would the most considerable risks be?